# Shopware 5 - Last seen products is empty

Tags: shopware, shopware5

we´re using Shopware 5.6 and the "last seen products" are empty. Even if we switch to the Responsive-Standard-Template of Shopware we don´t see the products.
The box "zuletzt angesehene Artikel" (last seen products) is there, we only see the headline but no products.

Does somebody have an idea how to fix that?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Are there entries in the table s_statistics_article_impression?

Comment: @dnaumann Yes, there are 355738 entrys. The newest ones from today.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember this "last seen products" worked with cookies. Do you have some kind of cookie consent active which might be not accepting the necessary cookie?

Comment: Sounds like a solution. Whats the name of the cookie for the last seen products? @cdold